# Converting 32bit TIFF to Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, winforms, bitmap, tiff

I have a 32bit .tif file which is displayed in the image below by first ImageJ, and secondly my program. As you can guess, the way ImageJ displays the picture is correct.

[image: 2 ways to display my tiff]

I am converting the file to a Bitmap like this:

```
private Bitmap TiffToBmp()
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    int width;
    int height;
    float[] scanline32Bit;
    float[] buffer;

    using (Tiff original = Tiff.Open(file, "r"))
    {
        width = original.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH)[0].ToInt();
        height = original.GetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH)[0].ToInt();

        byte[] scanline = new byte[original.ScanlineSize()];
        scanline32Bit = new float[original.ScanlineSize() / 4];
        buffer = new float[width * height];

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) //loading the data into a buffer
        {
            original.ReadScanline(scanline, i);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(scanline, 0, scanline32Bit, 0, scanline.Length);

            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                buffer[i * width + j] = scanline32Bit[j];
            }
        }
    }

    bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);

    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];

    for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++) //creating Bitmap from buffer
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < data.Stride; x += 4)
        {
            bytes[y * data.Stride + x] = (byte)buffer[(y * data.Stride + x) / 4];
            bytes[y * data.Stride + x + 1] = (byte)buffer[(y * data.Stride + x) / 4];
            bytes[y * data.Stride + x + 2] = (byte)buffer[(y * data.Stride + x) / 4];
            bytes[y * data.Stride + x + 3] = 255;
        }
    }
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, data.Scan0, bytes.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);
    return bmp;
}
```

Using a RGBA Bitmap might seem a bit naive but it's necessary in further steps of the program. Also worth mentioning: XnView displays the file similar to mine, just the negative (from white to black instead of black to white). When opening the file it notices me that it converts the image to RGB with 8bits per channel (the same thing I'm doing) and falsely claims the .tif is 16bit instead of 32bit.

Has someone an idea of what I am doing wrong?
It seems to me that the error comes purely from some kind of misuse of structs or wrongly converting between them (from float to byte and so on).
I am using `BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic` from the [the .NET version of original libtiff library](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/)

**edit:** after some research I found out that `original.ReadScanline(scanline, i)` returns seemingly weird values and converts them via `Buffer.BlockCopy(...)` to the stripes appearing in the image. For example the 4 bytes (read from `scanline`) of the pixel `(x = 0, y = 0)` are `0, 0, 200, 6`, the corresponding 8bit pixel value (read from `scanline32Bit`) turns out to be 110. Of Pixel `(x = width, y = 0)` the 4 bytes are `0, 128, 111, 68` and the 8bit value displayed is 958 corresponding to 190. So now I think there's something wrong with one of those steps but I actually have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Can you post a link to the original image? I'll take a look once you have.

Comment: One thing I immediately see is that you are accessing your `buffer` using the stride of your bitmap, while your `buffer` is exactly Width*Height bytes, so it only holds one byte per pixel. I think it should just use `[y+x/4]` as index. And, why doesn't your x loop start from 0?

Comment: Just to mention what I had noticed during my edit: your second to last `for` loop seems to have no closing `}` brace.

Comment: Edits: added the } brace, was a copy&paste mishap. Accessing the buffer this way works perfectly fine for other files, namely 16bit .tifs I have been working on so far, this problem is new to 32bit .tifs

Comment: @BitBank: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/669a162220d84afc720648217931dba020180212090135/e520aa), thanks, appreciate the effort

Comment: Thanks for the image. It's 32-bit grayscale compressed with LZW. My code doesn't properly decode it (yet), but I'll fix it and let you know.

Comment: "32-bit grayscale compressed with LZW" Ahh. TIFF. Still stands for "Thousands of Incompatible File formats".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind using existing code, there is this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8279/ImageConverter-Converts-images-to-a-specific-image

The author (not me, BTW) provides both the C# source and an executable. I used the executable to convert a TIF (created using paint.net) to a BMP, so I presume the source will be useful to you. I was able to open the author's solution using VS 2017 (VS upgraded both the solution and project to work in the current VS environment). The conversion is based on the System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat class